# srcset attribute in img tag

Tags: html, image

recently I see what many webpage specially some build with WordPress have img tag like the below.

```
<img src="smallImg.jpg" srcset="mediumImg.jpg 1000w, largeImg.jpg 2000w" alt="caigi">
```

I know that srcset is used in picture tag source tag;

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

I do not really understand what 1000w or 2000w mean, and which browsers accept srcset attribute.
can anyone expalain it clearly?

Comment: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) or [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) already looked?

Comment: https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-images/